# In Laravel, if you create $ php artisan make:model Staff -m why is it Laravel did not pluralized the word staff to staffs?

Tags: php, laravel, templates, frameworks, dependencies

Screenshot of making a model via git bash

[image]

Comment: Because it's a plural word. Take a look at [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/does-staff-take-a-plural-verb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel includes doctrine library to perform string manipulations with regard to uppercase/lowercase and singular/plural forms of words.
Staff is a collective noun... it should have singular verb. Actually, doctrine library does consider the word "staff" as a plural noun. So, it does not make "staffs". Actually you can also check to the word "people"; it will not be converted to "peoples" as it is already a plural.

Answer (score 0):

The word "Staff" is already Plural. So nothing wrong with your code.

In case you doesn't like the way laravel pick the name, you could always force it manually:

**Change your Migrations:**

1. On your migration file, find the word "staff" and replace it to "staffs"

**Change your Model:**

1. on your Model **App/Staff.php**
2. Add **protected $table = 'staffs';** under the class

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#defining-models)